# How to close modal from async function BreezeJS

Tags: javascript, breeze, durandal

I'm trying to close a modal view after a async function has been triggered. The async function is BreezeJS. The framework I'm using is DurandalJS.

The thing is I have an inputfield where you can input a value.

If this value already exists then I get this value, and when you click the button that is bound to the OK function the modal closes nicely.

But if this value doesn't exist it needs to be created (fetched in an async function). After a call gets back from the server (yo I created a new entity, and this is the ID of the row) then the modal should be closed, but that part (closing the modal from an async function) is NOT working. Please help and thanks in advance

```
define(function (require) {
    var dataservice = require('services/dataservice'),
        logger = require('services/logger'),
        isLoading = ko.observable(false),
        everythingFilledIn = ko.observable(true),
        containerNumberCorrect = ko.observable(true),
        customersRaw = ko.observableArray([]),
        containersRaw = ko.observableArray([]),
        billingCustomer = ko.observable(),
        customer = ko.observable(),
        container = ko.observable(),
        updaterTriggered = ko.observable(false),
        containerNumber = ko.observable();

    function init() {
        dataservice = new dataservice('api/data');

        dataservice.getAllRows('Customers').then(function (data) {
            isLoading(true);
            data.results.forEach(function (item) {
                customersRaw.push(item);
            });
            isLoading(false);
        }).fail(function () {
        });

        dataservice.getAllRows('Containers').then(function (data) {
            isLoading(true);
            data.results.forEach(function (item) {
                containersRaw.push(item);
            });
            isLoading(false);
        }).fail(function () {
        });
    }

    init();

    estimateStart = function (loggedInEmployee) {
        this.customers = function () {
            var customerName = [];
            mapCustomers = {};
            var data = customersRaw();
            $.each(data, function (i, customer) {
                mapCustomers[customer.Name()] = customer;
                customerName.push(customer.Name());
            });
            return customerName;
        };

        this.containers = function () {
            var containerNumber = [];
            mapContainers = {};
            var data = containersRaw();
            $.each(data, function (i, container) {
                mapContainers[container.ContainerNumber()] = container;
                containerNumber.push(container.ContainerNumber());
            });
            return containerNumber;
        };

        this.customer = customer;
        this.billingCustomer = billingCustomer;
        this.container = container;
        this.isLoading = isLoading;
        this.containerNumberCorrect = containerNumberCorrect;
        this.containerNumber = containerNumber;
        this.everythingFilledIn = everythingFilledIn;

        this.containerNumber.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            if (newValue.length < 13) {
                containerNumberCorrect(false);
                return;
            }
            else {
                checkContainerNumberFunction(newValue);
            }
        });



        /* //old this is for when I bind a css but that wont work because Bootstrap overwrites! Thats why the style binding in the html!
        this.containerDigitStatus = ko.computed(function () {
            return containerNumberCorrect() ? "containerNumberCorrect" : "containerNumberIncorrect";
        }, this);*/

        this.containerupdatefunction = function(item, element) {
            containerNumber(item);
            return item;
        };

        this.closeThisModal = function(jsonObj) {
            containerNumber("");
            billingCustomer(null);
            customer(null);
            container(null);
            updaterTriggered(false);
            this.modal.close(jsonObj);
        };

        this.ok = function() {
            if (this.containerNumberCorrect()) {
                try {
                    var metadataStore = dataservice.getMetadataStore();
                    var jsonObj = [];
                    var containerIDToUse = -999;
                    var goASynch = false;

                    if (container() == null) {
                        var type = metadataStore.getEntityType('tblContainer');
                        var newContainer = type.createEntity({ ContainerNumber: this.containerNumber() });
                        dataservice.manager.addEntity(newContainer);
                        dataservice.manager.saveChanges().then(function (data) {
                            jsonObj.push({
                                CustomerID: mapCustomers[customer()].CustomerID,
                                BillingCustomerID: mapCustomers[billingCustomer()].CustomerID,
                                ContainerID: data.entities[0].ContainerID()
                            });
                            containerNumber("");
                            billingCustomer(null);
                            customer(null);
                            container(null);
                            updaterTriggered(false);
                            this.self.close(jsonObj);// closeThisModal(jsonObj);
                        });
                        goASynch = true;
                    } else {
                        //container id van bestaande hier invoeren.
                        containerIDToUse = container().ContainerID();
                    }
                    if (!goASynch) {
                        jsonObj.push({
                            CustomerID: mapCustomers[this.customer()].CustomerID,
                            BillingCustomerID: mapCustomers[this.billingCustomer()].CustomerID,
                            ContainerID: containerIDToUse
                        });
                        this.closeThisModal(jsonObj);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    logger.logError("Error: " + err + "                    Possible unrecognized customers or containers!", null, null, true);
                }
            } else {
                logger.logError("The provide container number is NOT valid!", null, null, true);
            }
        };

        function checkContainerNumberFunction(containerNumberToCheck) {
            try {
                if (mapContainers[containerNumberToCheck].ContainerNumber() != undefined) {
                    container(mapContainers[containerNumberToCheck]);
                    containerNumberCorrect(true);
                    return;
                }
            } catch (err) {

            }

            if (containerNumberToCheck.trim().length == 13) {
                $.get(
                    "http://localhost:60312/api/baseapi/checkContainerDigit?digit=" + containerNumberToCheck,
                    function (data) {
                        if (data == true) {
                            container(null);
                            containerNumberCorrect(true);
                        } else {
                            containerNumberCorrect(false);
                        }
                        updaterTriggered(false);
                    }
                );
            } else {
                containerNumberCorrect(false);
                updaterTriggered(false);
            }
        };
    };

    estimateStart.prototype.updateViewAfterCustomerSelection = function (item) {
        customer(item);
        billingCustomer(item);
        return item;
    };
    /*
    estimateStart.prototype.ok = function () {
        if (this.containerNumberCorrect()) {
            try {
                var metadataStore = dataservice.getMetadataStore();
                var jsonObj = [];
                var containerIDToUse = -999;
                var goASynch = false;

                if (container() == null) {
                    var type = metadataStore.getEntityType('tblContainer');
                    var newContainer = type.createEntity({ ContainerNumber: this.containerNumber() });
                    dataservice.manager.addEntity(newContainer);
                    dataservice.manager.saveChanges().then(function(data) {
                        jsonObj.push({
                            CustomerID: mapCustomers[customer()].CustomerID,
                            BillingCustomerID: mapCustomers[billingCustomer()].CustomerID,
                            ContainerID: data.entities[0].ContainerID()
                        });
                        containerNumber("");
                        billingCustomer(null);
                        customer(null);
                        container(null);
                        updaterTriggered(false);
                        closeModalFunction(jsonObj);
                    });
                    goASynch = true;
                } else {
                    //container id van bestaande hier invoeren.
                    containerIDToUse = container().ContainerID();
                }
                if (!goASynch) {
                    jsonObj.push({
                        CustomerID: mapCustomers[this.customer()].CustomerID,
                        BillingCustomerID: mapCustomers[this.billingCustomer()].CustomerID,
                        ContainerID: containerIDToUse
                    });
                    this.closeThisModal(jsonObj);
                }
            } catch(err) {
                logger.logError("Error: " + err + "                    Possible unrecognized customers or containers!", null, null, true);
            }
        } else {
            logger.logError("The provide container number is NOT valid!", null, null, true);
        }
    };
    */
    /*
    estimateStart.prototype.closeThisModal = function(jsonObj) {
            containerNumber("");
            billingCustomer(null);
            customer(null);
            container(null);
            updaterTriggered(false);
            this.modal.close(jsonObj);
    };
    */
    estimateStart.prototype.closeModal = function () {
        updaterTriggered(false);
        return this.modal.close("close");
    };
    return estimateStart;
});
```

I also tried `var self= this;` but that won't work either!

Comment: For the fact I'm saying var self= this; wont work, that is correct if you put it OUTSIDE your VM, see answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. posting code as above with while working:
Put var `self = this;`in the `VM` so in this case in `estimateStart = function (loggedInEmployee) {`

```
define(function (require) {
    var dataservice = require('services/dataservice'),
        logger = require('services/logger'),
        isLoading = ko.observable(false),
        everythingFilledIn = ko.observable(true),
        containerNumberCorrect = ko.observable(true),
        customersRaw = ko.observableArray([]),
        containersRaw = ko.observableArray([]),
        billingCustomer = ko.observable(),
        customer = ko.observable(),
        container = ko.observable(),
        updaterTriggered = ko.observable(false),
        containerNumber = ko.observable();

    function init() {
        dataservice = new dataservice('api/data');

        dataservice.getAllRows('Customers').then(function (data) {
            isLoading(true);
            data.results.forEach(function (item) {
                customersRaw.push(item);
            });
            isLoading(false);
        }).fail(function () {
        });

        dataservice.getAllRows('Containers').then(function (data) {
            isLoading(true);
            data.results.forEach(function (item) {
                containersRaw.push(item);
            });
            isLoading(false);
        }).fail(function () {
        });
    }

    init();

    estimateStart = function (loggedInEmployee) {
        var self = this;

        this.customers = function () {
            var customerName = [];
            mapCustomers = {};
            var data = customersRaw();
            $.each(data, function (i, customer) {
                mapCustomers[customer.Name()] = customer;
                customerName.push(customer.Name());
            });
            return customerName;
        };

        this.containers = function () {
            var containerNumber = [];
            mapContainers = {};
            var data = containersRaw();
            $.each(data, function (i, container) {
                mapContainers[container.ContainerNumber()] = container;
                containerNumber.push(container.ContainerNumber());
            });
            return containerNumber;
        };

        this.customer = customer;
        this.billingCustomer = billingCustomer;
        this.container = container;
        this.isLoading = isLoading;
        this.containerNumberCorrect = containerNumberCorrect;
        this.containerNumber = containerNumber;
        this.everythingFilledIn = everythingFilledIn;

        this.containerNumber.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            if (newValue.length < 13) {
                containerNumberCorrect(false);
                return;
            }
            else {
                checkContainerNumberFunction(newValue);
            }
        });



        /* //old this is for when I bind a css but that wont work because Bootstrap overwrites! Thats why the style binding in the html!
        this.containerDigitStatus = ko.computed(function () {
            return containerNumberCorrect() ? "containerNumberCorrect" : "containerNumberIncorrect";
        }, this);*/

        this.containerupdatefunction = function(item, element) {
            containerNumber(item);
            return item;
        };

        this.closeThisModal = function(jsonObj) {
            containerNumber("");
            billingCustomer(null);
            customer(null);
            container(null);
            updaterTriggered(false);
            this.modal.close(jsonObj);

        };

        this.ok = function() {
            if (this.containerNumberCorrect()) {
                try {
                    var metadataStore = dataservice.getMetadataStore();
                    var jsonObj = [];
                    var containerIDToUse = -999;
                    var goASynch = false;

                    if (container() == null) {
                        var type = metadataStore.getEntityType('tblContainer');
                        var newContainer = type.createEntity({ ContainerNumber: this.containerNumber() });
                        dataservice.manager.addEntity(newContainer);
                        dataservice.manager.saveChanges().then(function (data) {
                            jsonObj.push({
                                CustomerID: mapCustomers[customer()].CustomerID,
                                BillingCustomerID: mapCustomers[billingCustomer()].CustomerID,
                                ContainerID: data.entities[0].ContainerID()
                            });

                        }).fin(function() {
                            containerNumber("");
                            billingCustomer(null);
                            customer(null);
                            container(null);
                            updaterTriggered(false);

                            //this.closeThisModal(jsonObj);
                            self.modal.close(jsonObj);// closeThisModal(jsonObj);
                        });
                        goASynch = true;
                    } else {
                        //container id van bestaande hier invoeren.
                        containerIDToUse = container().ContainerID();
                    }
                    if (!goASynch) {
                        jsonObj.push({
                            CustomerID: mapCustomers[this.customer()].CustomerID,
                            BillingCustomerID: mapCustomers[this.billingCustomer()].CustomerID,
                            ContainerID: containerIDToUse
                        });
                        this.closeThisModal(jsonObj);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    logger.logError("Error: " + err + "                    Possible unrecognized customers or containers!", null, null, true);
                }
            } else {
                logger.logError("The provide container number is NOT valid!", null, null, true);
            }
        };

        function checkContainerNumberFunction(containerNumberToCheck) {
            try {
                if (mapContainers[containerNumberToCheck].ContainerNumber() != undefined) {
                    container(mapContainers[containerNumberToCheck]);
                    containerNumberCorrect(true);
                    return;
                }
            } catch (err) {

            }

            if (containerNumberToCheck.trim().length == 13) {
                $.get(
                    "http://localhost:60312/api/baseapi/checkContainerDigit?digit=" + containerNumberToCheck,
                    function (data) {
                        if (data == true) {
                            container(null);
                            containerNumberCorrect(true);
                        } else {
                            containerNumberCorrect(false);
                        }
                        updaterTriggered(false);
                    }
                );
            } else {
                containerNumberCorrect(false);
                updaterTriggered(false);
            }
        };
    };

    estimateStart.prototype.updateViewAfterCustomerSelection = function (item) {
        customer(item);
        billingCustomer(item);
        return item;
    };
    /*
    estimateStart.prototype.ok = function () {
        if (this.containerNumberCorrect()) {
            try {
                var metadataStore = dataservice.getMetadataStore();
                var jsonObj = [];
                var containerIDToUse = -999;
                var goASynch = false;

                if (container() == null) {
                    var type = metadataStore.getEntityType('tblContainer');
                    var newContainer = type.createEntity({ ContainerNumber: this.containerNumber() });
                    dataservice.manager.addEntity(newContainer);
                    dataservice.manager.saveChanges().then(function(data) {
                        jsonObj.push({
                            CustomerID: mapCustomers[customer()].CustomerID,
                            BillingCustomerID: mapCustomers[billingCustomer()].CustomerID,
                            ContainerID: data.entities[0].ContainerID()
                        });
                        containerNumber("");
                        billingCustomer(null);
                        customer(null);
                        container(null);
                        updaterTriggered(false);
                        closeModalFunction(jsonObj);
                    });
                    goASynch = true;
                } else {
                    //container id van bestaande hier invoeren.
                    containerIDToUse = container().ContainerID();
                }
                if (!goASynch) {
                    jsonObj.push({
                        CustomerID: mapCustomers[this.customer()].CustomerID,
                        BillingCustomerID: mapCustomers[this.billingCustomer()].CustomerID,
                        ContainerID: containerIDToUse
                    });
                    this.closeThisModal(jsonObj);
                }
            } catch(err) {
                logger.logError("Error: " + err + "                    Possible unrecognized customers or containers!", null, null, true);
            }
        } else {
            logger.logError("The provide container number is NOT valid!", null, null, true);
        }
    };
    */
    /*
    estimateStart.prototype.closeThisModal = function(jsonObj) {
            containerNumber("");
            billingCustomer(null);
            customer(null);
            container(null);
            updaterTriggered(false);
            this.modal.close(jsonObj);
    };
    */
    estimateStart.prototype.closeModal = function () {
        updaterTriggered(false);
        return this.modal.close("close");
    };
    return estimateStart;
});
```